# projective limit of all the localizations of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, localization

I struggle to show that for any ring $A$
$$\varprojlim_{f \in A} A_f = A$$

Comment: Isn't this just another way of stating the usual universal property of localizations?

Comment: Maybe but from the universal property of each localizations I don't know how to prove this assertion by proving that $A$ satisfies the universal property of the direct limit.

Comment: In the first place what is the preorder you are using? Hint: it has a least element...

Comment: I would say that we use something like $f \leq g$ if $f|g$